# Redis taking RDB dump even if save is disabled

Tags: redis

I have configured my redis cluster with the following config:

```
appendonly no
save ""
```

But I found out that my redis is taking a back up and has taken a backup recently. My use case doesn't require any rdb save to be done. Am I missing some thing?

Comment: Perhaps someone called the [`SAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/save) or [`BGSAVE`](https://redis.io/commands/bgsave) commands?

Answer (score 1):

For disable all backups in redis go to redis.conf file do the following:

- Comment all `save` directives, by default there are three of them.

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

- Disable appendonly (set `appendonly` to `no`)